# Can I generate table schema from a model class?

Tags: c#, mysql

As database I use MySql.
I want to generate table schema of a model class?
Is this possible?

For example I have a class named Courses that look like this:

```
public class Courses 
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Students> AttendeesStudents { get; set; }
    }
```

Having this information I want to create the table schema that will look something like this

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
  Id varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  KEY IX_UNIQUE_UPDATE (Name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You may need to include meta information as attributes in your model, then generating sql command shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's what is done by Entity Framework. Look for MySQL-specific instructions - https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/7.2.php or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: You can use NHibernate or Entity Framework to do this.